# Max function working differently in SQL Server and redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

There is a column describe which has values like 'Year end bookings' and 'Year end FAHAB'.when a Max function is applied on the column it returns 'Year end FAHAB' in SQL server but when the same thing is done in Amazon redshift it returns 'Year end bookings'.

SQL server:

Select max(describe)

'Year end FAHAB'

Redshift:

Select max(describe)

'Year end bookings'

Comment: yes - if you make them both UPPER then it should be more consistent

Comment: in your question you state: `Year end bookings` and `Year end FAHAB` in the results the first is `Year end Bookings` iwth a capital B so which one is it? And is likely that redshift is considering the ASCII character number to sort alphabetically so capital "F" comes prior to lowercase "b" (that is if the result is what you mention on your question)

Comment: examine the collation of each and case sensitivity